# Why is unity not recognising my left shift key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a simple empty object with a 3d character controller attached. This is the update function of my player movement script

```cs
// Do the ground check
isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDist, groundMask);
if (isGrounded && yMovement.y < 0)
{
    yMovement.y = -2; // reset the gravity velocity
}
    
// get the xz movement of the player
float xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float zMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
Vector3 xzMovement = transform.right * xMovement + transform.forward * zMovement;

// Check for sprinting
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Sprint"))
{
    xzMovement *= sprintMultiplier;
}
    
// Check if the player should jump
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
{
    yMovement.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
}

// move the player on xz
controller.Move(xzMovement * speed * Time.deltaTime);

// move the player on y
yMovement.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
controller.Move(yMovement * Time.deltaTime);
```

And during the sprinting check, no matter if the button is pressed or not, "xzMovement *= sprintingMultiplier" never gets called. Why is this?

By the way, in the input sprint is set up with a positive button of "left shift."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use `Input.GetKeyDown` for keyboard input. It has an overload for a string parameter. So just use `Input.GetKeyDown("Sprint"))`. Buttons are for mouse/controller input buttons. Can few more details [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html).

Comment: @TEEBQNE no actually not. The `GetKeyDown(string)` refers to actual key names like `"a"`, `"space"`, `"left shift"` etc. if OP has configured a virtual button called `"Sprint"` it can have various triggers such as a certain key on the keyboard, a joystick or controller button, etc. or as OP says the positive keyboard input `"left shift"`. `Input.GetKeyDown("Sprint")` will never work since (at least on my keyboard :P ) there is no such key called `Sprint` ;)

Comment: @derHugo Interesting good to know - thanks! And what a world to have a custom keyboard with a sprint key. One can dream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`Input.GetButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetButton.html) instead of `Input.GetButtonDown`.

`GetButtonDown` only returns true for a **single frame** when the button is pushed down, whereas `GetButton` returns true **every frame while** that button stays pushed down.

Comment: From OPs code it looks like these are intended to be only called **once**

Comment: @derHugo I think he got the point. Usually sprinting is activated by holding shift, ctrl or whatever. Jumping is handled well by setting movement only in frame when key is pressed, but multiplying sprint speed only when the key is pressed first doesn't seem to be right. I don't know what ```transform``` is in this context, but ```xzMovement``` is probably for this frame's movement delta and multipying it once wouldn't be noticable unless multiplier is very big.

Comment: @MarkSouls oh yes, sorry! I was so focused on the Jump part that I didn't realize OP actually asks about the Sprint part

Comment: GetButton looks like what I'm looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! :D And thanks @derHugo for the edit!